# Populate Array of Objects While Iterating in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to create an object called my_obj which will have an array inside called "values".
This "values" should have 'another_obj' which is of type 'array of objects' with multiple objects & it's attribute which is having only 'description'.

```
locals{
another_obj = [{
description = "my_description_1"
},
{
description = "my_description_2"
}]
}
```

**// this part needs to be corrected**

```
my_obj = {
for_each = { for entry in local.another_obj : entry.name => entry }
//Array named as value which I want to create  
"values" = [
{
description = each.value.description,
type = "STRING",
}]
}` `
```

***I am expecting 'my_obj' to look something like***

```
my_obj = {
"values" = [
{
description = "my_description_1",
type = "STRING"
},
{
description = "my_description_2",
type = "STRING",
}
]
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the code. Any errors?

Comment: the code under the commetn of '// this part needs to be corrected' is a vague way of what I wan to do, where I have written the code which doesn't work in terraform language.

I am new to terraform hence don't know how to iterate & create a new 'my_obj' as described in the Question.

Comment: Sorry, your code is not even valid TF code, so its difficult to see what you are doing. What `each.value.description` is supposed to be? it is invalid use of `each`.

Comment: 'each.value.description' is nothing but I am trying to get value for 'local.another_obj.description' as stated code block at very start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want as follows:

```
locals {
  my_obj = {
    values = [for value in local.another_obj:
      {
        description = value.description,
        type = "STRING"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

p.s. `each` is only used in resource or module blocks, not in regular loops.